# Is it possible to restore Google Authenticator on another phone?

Tags: google-authenticator

Suppose I lost the phone with Google Authenticator on it. How do I restore it on another phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to recover Google authenticator database](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177587/is-it-possible-to-recover-google-authenticator-database)

Comment: If you use an app like Authy it can sync 2FA codes to other devices, but otherwise you're going to have to go to each of your websites and set up 2FA on the new device again.

Comment: I don't think it's quite the same question, because that other question is about having deleted the files but still having access to the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have previously backed up the QR code/secret key while initially setting up your Google Authenticator, this is not possible. Otherwise, you can contact each account's support team for help.

Alternatively, you can use another Authentication app like Authy ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/authy/id494168017?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.authy.authy)) or TOTP Authenticator ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/totp-authenticator/id1404230533?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.authenticator.authservice2)). These apps provide the feature to securely backup your codes and account details, so you can switch phone easily.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, if you had stored the initial QR code of your service. In that case, just scan your initial QR code when creation in the Google Authenticator.

Comment: But what if I didn't? Actually I'm pretty sure I didn't.

Comment: @jayarjo: then no way to retrieve your data

Answer (score 0):

If you saved QR codes or secret keys in the moment of token enrollment, you should use them to restore your tokens on another phone. Otherwise, you should contact the Support team of the service which you protect with the Google Authenticator. They will help you to restore an access to your account. After this, you can issue tokens on your new phone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy `com.google.android.apps.authenticator2` from `data/data` to a safe backup location.
2. Locate the databases file in `com.google.android.apps.authenticator2/database/database` and view it with SQLite database viewer (included natively in Root Explorer)
3. Select `accounts` - it will display all of the registered accounts along with the secret code next to it
4. Open the Google Authenticator app and select "Enter a provided key" and copy the desired account code.

Comment: These codes gets changed over time, and in most cases are not reusable.

Comment: Thanks @Sixx, but the secrets column is encrypted, so that data is useless. What way can I restore it or is it all gone? I've the app backed up with 3 different ways, but couldn't restore it with any...